# Measure CPU and RAM Usage of Child Process

Tags: c#, process, cpu, ram, child-process

I have the following process:

```
public void Run()
        {

            ProcessStartInfo serverPInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("javaw", "-jar -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M \"C:\\Users\\David\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication8\\Debug\\craftbukkit.jar\" -o true -nojline");
            serverPInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            serverPInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            serverPInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            serverPInfo.UseShellExecute = false;


            serverP = new Process();
            serverP.StartInfo = serverPInfo;

            serverP.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ServerOutputDataReceived);
            serverP.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ServerErrorDataReceived);
            serverP.Start();


            serverP.BeginOutputReadLine();
            serverP.BeginErrorReadLine();
            serverP.WaitForExit();
        }
```

**How can I measure the process' CPU and RAM usage?**

I tried `serverP.WorkingSet64`, `serverP.PrivateMemorySize64` and `serverP.PagedMemorySize64`, but they all return constant values. None of them change (like the RAM usage meter in Task Manager).

I have no idea how to get the current CPU usage.

I looked on the internet, but most of the stuff I found was `PerformanceMonitor`. I don't want to use this since there may be more instances of the "javaw" process and I just want to measure the CPU and RAM usage of the child process I created in the code above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to fetch a fresh `Process` object from the PID everytime you want to get the RAM?

Comment: @ZoolWay I don't know how to do that. Could you please tell me how to do it or how exactly is it called so that I can Google it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PerformanceCounter` to measure only a child process activity. But you need to use its Process ID instead of Process Name. The counter's `RawValue` equals to `ProcessId`, when you create it.

[Here is an answer describing such technique.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9115662/1980492)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing as "current CPU usage". It can be measured only against some period of time, last 1 second for instance. You can use TotalProcessorTime property, measure it every second and subtract the previous value. This will give you how much time CPU was used in the last measurement period.
To measure RAM usage I'm using WorkingSet64 and PrivateMemorySize64 - this works well for me.