# Display used RAM continuously on control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a **process**

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", -jar test.jar);
```

and I need get RAM, CPU of `process p` is used in **realtime**

my code to get RAM is used but not in realtime:

```
while(true) {
    txtRamIsUsed.Text = BytesToReadableValue(p.PrivateMemorySize64);
}
```

```
public string BytesToReadableValue(long number)
{
    List<string> suffixes = new List<string> { " B", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB" };

    for (int i = 0; i < suffixes.Count; i++)
    {
        long temp = number / (int)Math.Pow(1024, i + 1);

        if (temp == 0)
        {
            return (number / (int)Math.Pow(1024, i)) + suffixes[i];
        }
    }

    return number.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "realtime"? Continuously display it?

Comment: It is constantly change in realtime

Comment: Use timer control to display it in some small duration.

Comment: Use a Timer, say every second, to update the label. Loops can’t be used for updates in Winforms and most other UIs because the event loop can’t process. This will also prevent wasting CPU in a hot-busy loop. There are many duplicates.

Comment: And How to get CPU of ` process p` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115436/performance-counter-by-process-id-instead-of-name

Comment: "realtime" is a hollow term without stating the specifications. There cannot be actual "realtime" on a non-realtime OS, anyway. So, what you actually mean is "update as tightly as possible", right?