# Performance monitoring with Web Gardening

Tags: .net, performancecounter, web-garden

Does anyone know hot to monitor performance of an application having web gardening implemented in it? Basically with web gardening implementation, there are multiple instances of w3wp process. So when our aim is to monitor Private Bytes of w3wp process & we have multiple processes to monitor, then what performance counters we need to add? For example, we are seeing multiple instances of w3wp process like w3wp, w3wp#1 and when we add counters in perfmon then do we need to select all the instances of w3wp process? If yes, then how to interpret the result later because the csv file will show private bytes for w3wp as well as w3wp#1 princesses as well.Same for garbage collection and time spent in GC?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue and found this solution:

http://openrent.blogspot.com/2008/01/multiple-clr-performance-counters.html

which was referenced here:

[Get Performance Counter Instance Name (w3wp#XX) from ASP.NET worker process ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113930/get-performance-counter-instance-name-w3wpxx-from-asp-net-worker-process-id)

You need to reload the performance counters for .net 2.0. Once reloaded you should see a "Process ID" counter.

This question came up in my searches before the above answer so hopefully this will help others in the same predicament.